# Can I turn this if statement into a function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am going to be repeating this code so I am trying to turn it into a function.
But I keep getting errors.
**EDIT**
No I am getting Error: Missing 1 positional argument: 'connection'
What would be the best way to place 'connection' in the method?

```
def sqlfirst(self, connection):
    firstname = str(self.first_entry.get())
    lastname = str(self.last_entry.get())     
    license = str(self.lic_entry.get())
    if (firstname and not lastname and not license):  # "You entered first name."
        try:
            connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=;Database=;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
        except pypyodbc.Error as ex:
            sqlstate = ex.args[0]
            if sqlstate == '28000':
                self.answer_label['text'] = "You do not have access." 
        cursor = connection.cursor() 
        SQLCommand = ("SELECT LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, L_LICNUMBER "      
            "FROM dbo. "   # table name
            "with (nolock)"
            "WHERE FIRSTNAME = ?")
        Values = [firstname]
        cursor.execute(SQLCommand,Values)
        return cursor.fetchmany(10)




def calculate2(self):
    results = self.sqlfirst()
    if results:

        self.output1.delete(0, END)
        self.output1.insert(0,results[2])
        connection.close()
        traceback.print_exc()
```

Below was my old code:

Can I turn the above into a function called so I can call sqlfirst(self) at any time?  I have tried:

```
def sqlfirst(self):
    firstname = str(self.first_entry.get())
    lastname = str(self.last_entry.get())     
    if (firstname and not lastname):  # "You entered first name."
        try:
            connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=;Database=;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
        except pypyodbc.Error as ex:
            sqlstate = ex.args[0]
            if sqlstate == '28000':
                self.answer_label['text'] = "You do not have access." 
        cursor = connection.cursor() 
        SQLCommand = ("SELECT LASTNAME "      
            "FROM dbo.NAME "   # table name
            "with (nolock)"
            "WHERE FIRSTNAME = ?")
        Values = [firstname]
        cursor.execute(SQLCommand,Values)
        results = cursor.fetchmany(10)



def calculate(self):
    self.sqlfirst()
        if results:

            self.output2.delete(0, END)
            self.output2.insert(0,results[2])
            connection.close()
```

Comment: You probably want to `return cursor.fetchmany(10)` at the end of the function instead of assigning it to a local variable which is then lost when the function exits. Then call the function like this: `results = sqlfirst()`.

Comment: ok, I'll try that.  btw, I think most of my problems are from my IDE and how it is using spaces and tabs.  I'm trying to mess with the settings now.

Comment: First, those are not functions, they've *methods*. Second, if you want help with errors, *show us a backtrace of the errors*.

Comment: where is your class definition?